# Initialize an array with different index starting point to any N?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been sitting here for a few hours now, trying to figure out how an array can be initialized with specified `array[index]`, no not `0-n`, but `n-N`, meaning that index can be: 3, and then it increments to N.

```
int array[];
std::iota(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 2);
```

That line does one thing, but not what I want. Since I filling up the values of the array as `bool` and setting all to `false` by default, but, index goes from `0-N`.

**Is it possible:**

```
int array[std::advance(iter, 2)]
```

When I run, `std::iota(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 2);` then output below looks as that, but, I want it to be: [2]:false, [3]:false, ... N.

**Output:**

```
[0]:2
[1]:3
[2]:4
[3]:5
[4]:6
[5]:7
[6]:8
[7]:9
[8]:10
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what output you're expecting. Could you add an example?

Comment: @cigien, I just want to initialize an array with false, but a different index and index++, meaning that if it starts from index = 5, it will continue to increment till N.

Comment: I'm sorry. I find the description difficult to understand. An example would be much better. Make a [mre] since your code doesn't actually compile, and show what output you would like instead.

Comment: You have an array of `int`, so you can't have `false`. Do you want to fill that with 0?

Comment: @cigien, yes I know. But, that's a minor issue. I want to know if there's a good way to start the index of an array from n to N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) to fill a range starting at index 2, with some value `N`, like this:

```
std::fill(std::begin(array) + 2, std::end(array), N);
```

Comment: I tried std::fill() before, but I guess I simply misunderstood it, and therefore move to try something else. ;-) Thanks a lot dude.

Answer (score -1):

Your use of `std::iota()` doesn't works because you have to explicit the size of the array.

If your starting and ending point are known compile-time, you can try something as follows

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto lastVal = 10;
   constexpr auto firstVal = 2;

   int array[lastVal-firstVal+1];

   std::iota(std::begin(array), std::end(array), firstVal);

   for ( auto const & x : array )
      std::cout << x << ' ';
    
   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

that prints

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Doesn't have an effect. Absolutely zero effect.

Comment: @JohnSmith - answer improved with a full compiling example that works with both clang++ and g++